# pytesseract fail to extract correct email id from image

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract to extract email id from images, using below code.

```
import pytesseract as ps
text = ps.image_to_string('./email_id.png')
print(text)
```

But the extarcted text is not correct. Example for image:

[image: Email Id]

it extracts email id as : **adarsh_1493@yahoo.com**

Similarly when I'm using below image:

[image: Image 2]

The result is coming as : **airiorceschooibegumpet@yahoo.com** .

I tried to follow few configs as suggested by different posts but nothing worked. (***Tesseract-OCR V5.0.0alpha20190708***)

Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Not working for me. I'm looking the solution using tesseract.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to preprocess the image.
I recommend the following types to begin with converting to grayscale and thresholding first:

```
# get grayscale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold gray image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Then try variations of noise removal, dilation and erosion.

```
# noise removal
cv2.medianBlur(thresh,5)
 
# dilation
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)
    
# erosion
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)
```